# Pannable-zoomable matplotlib / pandas UI plot for time-series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Let's say you have a time-series spanning over 1000 days. Here is how to plot it in a pannable (click and drag) and zoomable (both time x-axis and y-axis value):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['y'])
start = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = N)
for i in range(N):
    t = start + datetime.timedelta(days = i)
    df.ix[t] = {'y': math.sin(0.1 * i)}     # btw, is there a simpler way? I tried df.ix[t]['y'] = ... but unsuccessfully

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

But this UI lacks a number of features to make it look like a [realtime-updating trading chart](https://www.bitstamp.net/market/tradeview/), for example:

1. Have "click and drag to pan" feature enabled by default (without requiring to click on bottom toolbar cross icon)
2. Prevent to pan *after* the last date of the time-series
3. Add <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> x-axis zoom buttons
4. **Allow the plot to be updated in realtime when new values are added to the dataframe (maybe by another thread), and have an x-axis auto-scroll to let new values appear on the right**
5. (Minor UI: Remove the bottom icons, remove the black rectangle box, make background grey)

Of course, we could modify `matplotlib` source code / implement all these things one after another, but it feels like reinventing the wheel.

**Is there a ready-to-use interface for such plot in `pandas` and/or `matplotlib`?**

Note: I'm not looking for candlesticks, a simple curve is ok.

[image]

Comment: You do not need to touch the source code to implement those features in matplotlib. But of course implementation is a little bit of work. You may of course ask about any problem you have on your way to get there, but as a whole this question is too broad and hence not well suited for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm nearly sure that all of that has already been implemented somewhere, and probably directly available in `pandas` or `matplotlib` or another additional module, instead of reinventing the wheel. The goal of this question is to know if maybe this is already directly existant (but hard to find) in their API. I've already searched for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 since a long time, but haven't found something significant.

Comment: Consider the possibility that **1.** could be irrelevant to most people (a click to activate a function costs nothing, plus you could also use your keyboard to activate) **2.** could be a useless restriction (the user will see for himself that there is no more data coming up) **3.** could also be seen as useless since the zoom/pan tool already gives you the option to zoom in and out with your mouse much more ergonomically **4.** seems to be implemented by default, or else by a single call to `autoscale()` **5.** is rather a question of taste(use stylesheets to get your personal flavour in).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok for 5. But 1 2 3 4 are the standard for most trading interfaces.

Comment: Just to add that the matplotlib figure window is not a trading platform and was never intended to be one. But the good thing is that it is completely open for you to adjust to your likings. All of what you demand **is** possible. Just too broad to ask a single question about. Or, interpreting your question differently, be reminded that questions asking to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" are off-topic here as well.